# what is Sync event in solidity

Tags: web3js, solidity-0.8.x

I know Event is an inheritable member of a contract, when an event is emitted, it stores the arguments passed in transaction logs and this things are get stored into the blockchain.

But i see there is a Sync type event in Uniswap Pair.sol contract [HERE](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol)

```
event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);
```

Looking for expert opinions.

Answer (score 1):

In uniswap, when the balances of a pair are updated ( i.e, when someone buys or sell, usually), a function named `sync()` is called, which computes the new price, and updates the variable that track the pair balances. This function simply emits the `Sync()` event once it's done executing.